# When is a memory_order_seq_cst fence useful?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, memory-model, stdatomic

C++ supported *atomic* thread fences, that is fences guaranteeing properties for thread that use `std::atomic<>` operations, with the function `atomic_thread_fence`. It takes a memory order parameter to adjust the "strength" of the fence.

I understand that fences are **useful when not all atomic operations are done with a "strong" order**:

- when *not all* atomic reads (1) in a thread are acquire operations, you may find a use for an acquire fence;
- when *not all* atomic modifications (1) in a thread are release operations, you may find a use for a release fence.

(1) that includes RMW operations

So the usefulness of all these (acquire, release and acq_rel fences) is obvious: they allow threads that use atomic operations weaker than acq/rel (respectively) to synchronize properly.

But I don't understand where `memory_order_seq_cst` could be specifically needed as a fence:

- What's the implication of using weaker than `memory_order_seq_cst` atomic operations and a `memory_order_seq_cst` fence?
- What would specifically be guaranteed (in term of possible ordering of atomic operations) by a `memory_order_seq_cst` fence that wouldn't be guaranteed by `memory_order_acq_rel`?

Comment: If I remember it correctly, `atomic_thread_fence` should also affect regular (i.e. not through `atomic<>`) read and writes.

Comment: Presumably, such program would involve thread A doing normal writes (non atomic operations) and thread B observing these writes? **Would these threads be able to run concurrently without a data race**? In C++ data race => UB.

Answer (score 3):

No, a seq-cst-fence is not only both a release and an acquire-fence, but also provides some additional properties (see [Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++, 32.4.4-32.4.8](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)). A seq-cst fence is also part of the single total order of all sequentially consistent operations, enforcing the following observations:

- For an atomic operation *B* that reads the value of an atomic object *M*, if there is a `memory_order_seq_cst` fence *X* sequenced before *B*, then *B* observes either the last `memory_order_seq_cst` modification of *M* preceding *X* in the total order *S* or a later modification of *M* in its modification order.
- For atomic operations *A* and *B* on an atomic object *M*, where *A* modifies *M* and *B* takes its value, if there is a `memory_order_seq_cst` fence *X* such that *A* is sequenced before *X* and *B* follows *X* in *S*, then *B* observes either the effects of *A* or a later modification of *M* in its modification order.
- For atomic operations *A* and *B* on an atomic object *M*, where *A* modifies *M* and *B* takes its value, if there are `memory_order_seq_cst` fences *X* and *Y* such that *A* is sequenced before *X*, *Y* is sequenced before *B*, and *X* precedes *Y* in *S*, then *B* observes either the effects of *A* or a later modification of *M* in its modification order.

For example, I am using seq-cst fences in my hazard pointer implementation: https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium/blob/master/xenium/reclamation/impl/hazard_pointer.hpp
The thread acquiring a safe reference to some object uses seq-cst fence after storing the hazard pointer, but before re-reading the pointer to the object. The thread trying to reclaim some objects uses a seq-cst fence before gathering the active hazard pointers from all threads. Based on the rules above this ensures that either the thread trying to reclaim the object sees that some other thread has a HP for this object (i.e., the object is used), or the reload of thread trying to acquire the safe reference to the object returns a different pointer, indicating to that thread that the object has been removed and it has to perform a retry.