# About memory barrier

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-barriers

In a NUMA multi-CPU architecture, the initial value of `a` is 0 and it is in a shared state between CPU-x and CPU-y. At time t0, CPU-x executes `a = 1` followed immediately by an `smp_wmb`, and then at a later time t1, CPU-y executes `b = a` followed immediately by an `smp_rmb`. Is `b` guaranteed to be equal to `1` after the `smp_rmb`?

My understanding is that it is not guaranteed. Although `a = 1` is first written to its store buffer, then a read invalidate message is sent to CPU-y and added to CPU-y's invalidate queue, and an acknowledgment is sent back to CPU-x, CPU-y processes the invalidate queue after the `smp_rmb`, invalidating its cache and reading from CPU-x. However, at this time, CPU-x might be busy with something else and may not have had the chance to process the acknowledgment and flush the store buffer. Therefore, CPU-y could still read the old value of 0 from memory after the `smp_rmb`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Right, the `a=1` store could still be sitting in the store buffer of CPU-x, assuming by "execute" you mean the store address and data are written to the store buffer.  Or it retires from the ROB (reorder buffer) - commit to L1d cache can't happen before that, but it doesn't happen on retirement, it happens after.  A read-for-ownership (RFO) has to complete first.

Comment: No amount of barriers can guarantee visibility without other pre-conditions (like having already seen a store of another variable from that core, so acq / rel sync), only a long enough interval between t0 and t1.  Depending on the ISA (like x86 with in-order commit from the store buffer), and with large enough store buffers and high contention, the hypothetical worst case could be pretty long with all SB entries full with stores to highly-contended locations that have all cores hammering on them with atomic RMWs.  (You could even have cache-line-split `lock`s taking a bus lock.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thx! In summary, in general for multi CPUs arch, memory barriers can only guarantee ordering and not real-time visibility (due to propagation delays or out-of-order execution by CPUs to avoid waiting, causing temporal issues). To ensure visibility, it is necessary to establish a "happens-before" relationship. In the given scenario, even with the use of read/write or full memory barriers and clear write-before-read ordering in the physical timeline, it is still not guaranteed that a read will always observe a preceding write in a multi-CPU multi-core architecture. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Barriers just order this core's accesses to shared cache, giving ordering between operations on different variables by this thread.  They can't create atomicity or visibility.

Comment: It's barely even meaningful to say that a store executes "at the same time" as a load in another thread, unless you're specific about what you mean by "executes" and it involves commit to coherent cache (the point of visibility for a store) or reading from cache for a load.  (So "at the same time" is then impossible because of MESI, unless these are logical cores sharing a physical core, since commit can only happen while the cache line is exclusively owned, which prevents other readers). Although that's assuming an ISA not like POWER so no private store-forwarding between SMT logical cores.

Comment: (See [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27807118) for more about that, with independent writes to two *different* locations, and two readers that read in opposite orders. This is the IRIW litmus test.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I have another question now :-). Since memory barriers cannot guarantee that a write that occurs earlier in time will always be seen by a subsequent read after switching CPUs, how does the Linux kernel ensure visibility for the same thread when performing thread scheduling and CPU core switching?

Comment: release/acquire sync between the core storing the register context and the core loading that context is already required, which also takes care of user-space ordering.  Plus there's a full memory barrier in there somewhere in case of stuff like weakly ordered NT stores.  You're right that synchronization is required to not break single-threaded code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, I understand. But I have another question: Why did you specifically mention "Plus there's a full memory barrier in there somewhere in case of stuff like weakly ordered NT stores"? Regarding this question, I understand that establishing release/acquire dependency typically relies on a full memory barrier on any architecture, right? For example, before switching, we need to add smp_mb after the user code, followed by the kernel ctx used for synchronization. After switching, we need to first observe the kernel ctx in a loop, followed by smp_mb, and then execute the user code.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of x86, forgot this was an ISA-neutral question.  `smp_rmb()` and `smp_wmb()` don't require any asm instructions on x86 (just `barrier()` which is `asm("" ::: "memory")`), so acquire and release are free (*[C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179)*).  But `movntps` / `movnti` etc. are weakly ordered so don't respect those barriers.  That's why you'd need `_mm_sfence()` between them and a normal store to get release semantics.  And there's the possibility of NT loads from WC memory...

Comment: Also no, release/acquire doesn't require a full barrier, it's not necessary to block StoreLoad reordering. https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ . Oh right, *that*'s why you need a full barrier on context switches, because you basically need sequential consistency to match the ordering guarantees for a thread reading its own stores.  And BTW, you don't always need or want separate barriers.  On AArch64 for example, `stlr` / `ldapr` are a fair bit more efficient AFAIK than running fence insns before a plain `str` store and after a plain `ldr` load.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thx! I am a beginner in this area, and I need to study your response carefully. Perhaps I need to learn more to fully understand.

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ 
and https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ and https://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/ are very good.

Comment: @PeterCordes Then I remembered another question. For the current memory model, the highest level of consistency achievable is sequential consistency. Therefore, in terms of ordering, after a store operation, a happens-before relationship must be established through synchronization before a subsequent load operation to ensure that the content of the store operation, even for non-RMW (Read-Modify-Write) atomic operations, is observed in the correct order.

Comment: Taking C++ as an example: suppose we have x.store(1) executed in thread 1, and y = x.load() executed in thread 2. Even with a memory order of seq_cst, it is not guaranteed that y will observe the value 1. However, for RMW atomic operations, my understanding is that they satisfy linearizability, meaning that due to the causal feedback provided by RMW, the result is always linear.

Comment: For example, if we replace the previous example with fetch_add operations and x is initially 0, then if thread 1 executes x.fetch_add(1, relaxed) first, and then thread 2 executes y = x.fetch_add(1, relaxed), y will definitely be equal to 2. 
Right？

Comment: That's correct. Both operations were on the same object, `x`, so they're linearizable.  Same for `x.store(relaxed)` - the sequence of results that `x.load` could observe (from a thread not doing any stores to `x`) is the modification-order of `x` that all threads can agree on

Comment: Store-forwarding allows a thread to see its own stores early, but still consistent with the modification order.  There's no guarantee that a load in a loop will see every value in the mod order, but a store from this thread will "shadow" any that end up before it in the modification order.  see also *[Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50609934)*). So that's one way atomic RMWs are different from pure stores.

Comment: Anyway, sequential-consistency is mostly only hard (expensive barriers) with ops on different variables.  That's what requires that SC stores not reorder with later SC loads in the same thread.  Most ISAs do that with a full barrier after or as part of the SC store, but AArch64 is only as strong as ISO C++ allows (but without IRIW reordering), with `stlr` (release store) having a special interaction with `ldar` (acquire load), so SC stores can reorder with other non-SC loads (relaxed and acquire on AArch64 new enough to use `ldapr` for those, Partial orders, or Processor-consistency.)

Comment: See also https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html for how various ops and fences map to asm for various CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I need to modify the example I mentioned earlier about fetch_add: For example, if we replace the previous example with fetch_add operations and x is initially 0, then if thread 1 executes x.fetch_add(1, relaxed) first, and then thread 2 executes y = x.fetch_add(1, relaxed), y will definitely be equal to 1, since we observe that y is 1, we can infer from the semantics of fetch_add that at this moment x must be equal to 2. Therefore, any subsequent x.load operation from the same thread will definitely observe x as 2.

Comment: BUT(1) I am confused by your response. It seems to imply that, even in any instruction architecture, a store operation from thread-1 in a store-load scenario will be observed by a load operation from thread-2 that occurs later in terms of timing. However, based on my previous understanding, although atomic operations on an object satisfy the modification order, it only guarantees sequential consistency and does not provide visibility guarantees.

Comment: (2) From a general perspective, the highest level of memory consistency implemented by instruction architectures is typically only sequential consistency, which does not provide real-time visibility. Therefore, I believe that after a store operation, a load operation executed by another thread may not establish a happens-before relationship, and the load operation is not guaranteed to observe the value stored by another thread. I'm not sure if there is a problem with my understanding.

Comment: I didn't intend to imply anything about how soon a third thread would start seeing new values in the modification-order of `x` (i.e. seeing pure stores) if it was looping on `x.load()`.  In your example with atomic RMWs, you assert that thread 2 lost the race to get exclusive ownership of the cache line containing `x` and do the atomic RMW, so that nails down which operation takes which place in  the modification order.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that the thread which starts attempting to `fetch_add` will be the one that goes first; e.g. consider an LL/SC machine like ARMv7 or ARMv8.0 where the first thread runs `ldrex` / `add` regs / `strex` in a retry loop, and the first iteration of `strex` failed because another core did its own `ldrex` so this core lost exclusive ownership.  And the core that started trying second ends up finishing first.  The value is sees is still the current latest in the modification order since the first thread's RMW hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Anyway, pure stores on the same object from one or multiple threads will happen in some order that no readers will disagree on; there is a "modification order" for each object separately which is determined by MESI cache-coherency, the order in which cores got ownership of the line to commit stores to it.  When you have the same thread doing both stores and loads on the same object with less than seq_cst ordering, then store-forwarding from the store buffer creates effects that would be different than with only atomic RMWs.

Comment: The "latest value" guarantee for RMWs is best understood in terms of the modification-order, not just wall-clock time or clock cycles.  If two cores attempt to start atomic RMWs "at the same time" in clock cycles, at least one of them will have to stall or retry.  Just like for pure stores, one of them will get MESI exclusive ownership first for long enough to do its RMW.  The diff is there's a load that happens during that same window of exclusive ownership so the ordering is observable in terms of those load results, not just the mod order which a third thread looping `x.load` might miss

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand what you mean. But the scenario I'm considering is this: a service has a status variable s, initialized to 0 (representing 'disabled'), and after starting up, it changes to 1 (representing 'enabled'), and then it begins to listen on the RPC server port to provide services externally. Temporally, RPC requests will only come in after the startup and listening has begun. If during the service process s changes from 'enabled' to 'disabled' (s: 1 -> 0) due to an admin command, then the RPC requests need to return EAGAIN.

Comment: I understand that the highest performance implementation of s is not to use locks, but to directly define it as std::atomic<uint8_t> s, and execute s.store(0, std::memory_order_relaxed) when disabling. When checking upon RPC entry, execute `s.fetch_aNd(255, std::memory_order_relaxed)` instead of s.load(std::memory_order_relaxed). `fetch_and` is an RMW operation that can guarantee linearizability across any ISA architecture, whereas using `load` cannot guarantee linearizability.

Comment: For example, if s is currently 1, with load, it is possible for one thread to store s as 0 and another thread to load s and get 1, but `fetch_and(255)` will definitely see s as 0. So, my point is that RMW operations, because they can observe an effect, naturally establish a synchronization relationship, while non-RMW `load` operations cannot, and must rely on other state variables to establish a synchronization relationship through looping before observation to ensure linearizability.

Comment: If you're worried about minimizing latency from when the admin command is received to when the last request is served, it might be a wash.  With all worker threads spamming `.fetch_add(0, relaxed)` (which can use x86 `lock xadd`, unlike `fetch_and` which needs a retry loop) or `compare_exchange_strong(expected=0, 0, relaxed)`, the thread attempting to store a `0` might take a while to get MESI ownership of the line to commit its store.  Although in realistic use-cases where workers take significant time per request, only very high core counts would give high contention.

Comment: Anyway, yes RMWs make it linearizable, but we don't need that for this use-case.  There can still be threads that receive an RPC request nanoseconds after the admin pressed enter on the disable command, but they still get served because the store hasn't run yet, or the worker thread won the race to get exclusive ownership of the cache line before the admin thread's pure store.  I don't see any real value in a slow RMW bouncing around a cache line when we could just have fast read-only checks of a cache line that normally stays on in Shared state.  Practical inter-core latency is very similar.

Comment: So either way, within probably a microsecond of running the store from the admin thread, all worker threads will see the flag as disabled even if they only use read-only checks, on typical hardware.  Especially on x86 where LoadLoad reordering isn't architecturally allowed so early load can only be done speculatively.  Low inter-thread latency is a selling point or at least something architects aim for.  See also  [Why set the stop flag using \`memory\_order\_seq\_cst\`, if you check it with \`memory\_order\_relaxed\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70581645)

Comment: See also the "latest value" section in [Is a memory barrier required to read a value that is atomically modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71722126) .  The much higher cost of an atomic RMW vs. a pure load doesn't make any sense for a use-case like this. It's something you could experiment with, like storing a timestamp from RDTSC, and having readers that also check the TSC and record the latest timestamp where they didn't see the non-zero "admin" timestamp which also means stop, using either atomic RMWs or pure loads. With some busy work so they're not just hammering

Comment: @PeterCordes For this example, I'm actually concerned about the scenario where disabling has already been completed (the administrator has received a response and is confident that no RPC will be processed from that point onwards), but subsequent RPC requests, due to the sequential consistency achieved by the load operation, see the state as enabled and proceed with the execution of the request (although fetch_add(0) guarantees that the state seen is disabled and rejects the request). This is unacceptable for the administrator.

Comment: However, based on what you're saying, even in the case of store-load, this issue would not occur in practical situations, and it only exists in theory. Is that correct?

Comment: I think we're talking about a few microseconds at most for a core to drain its invalidation queue, even in the worst case where all invalidated lines were dirty in Modified state and need to be written back to L3, not just dropped.  (Except this one Shared line holding the flag).  So if we're talking about a human administrator, way too fast to matter.  If we're talking about freeing or modifying resources once worker threads aren't looking at them, we need to know when the last worker finishes, not when the last one could have started.

Comment: But yes, even if the admin thread does a store + a full barrier to avoid reporting completion until the store is globally visible, apparently it could still just be pending in the invalidation queue of some cores, making it possible for a pure load to still read the old value.  Where I think that wouldn't be possible with an RMW.  So that's interesting, finally an example of an invalidation queue doing something. Mixing wall-clock time with memory ordering is always a dicey prospect; for correctness of algorithms, just don't rely in absolute wall-clock times, only on seeing stores or not.

Comment: And BTW, the existence of a modification-order for a single variable is a separate guarantee from sequential **consistency**.  You aren't getting ordering of these ops wrt. any other variables, just linearizability of the ops on that one shared variable, and that comes from MESI coherency itself.  IDK what you're saying about store-load (is that in reference to older comments?  I've been replying in comments on another Q&A about MESI and atomicity for Java `volatile` for the past couple days too, making it a bit hard to keep them straight.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I understand what you mean, thank you very much!

Comment: @PeterCordes But your response has introduced another confusion for me. You mentioned "just linearizability of the ops on that one shared variable, and that comes from MESI coherency itself." However, I have always believed that at the C++ level, the operations on a single atomic variable are at most sequentially consistent, not linearizable. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on exactly what "linearizable" means in general or the way you're using it.  I thought it meant you could make a straight-line diagram that included all operations (of the set of ops you're considering) which explained the values read by each op that is a read.  Relaxed atomic RMWs on one location are linearizable in that sense because they read the "latest value".  (Only one core at a time can have MESI exclusive ownership... unless there are multiple logical cores sharing an L1d cache.  But even then HW has to guarantee that 100x fetch_add(1) doesn't lose any counts.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks again! I understand what you mean now. When I mentioned "linearizable," I was actually referring to the concept of linearizability(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability), which is a form of consistency.

Comment: Sequential consistency means that all load results are explainable by some interleaving of program order of operations across threads, without any reordering within any thread.  C++ gives SC for data-race-free programs that don't use any memory_order weaker than `seq_cst` for atomics, only mutexes and `seq_cst` atomics.  Consistency is about order between operations on *different* locations, so IDK what it means to say that ops on a single variable are sequentially consistent.

Comment: “so IDK what it means to say that ops on a single variable are sequentially consistent”, You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model#Sequential_consistency

Comment: Yeah, that wiki article is where I got my understanding of Linearizability as being able to put operations into a non-overlapping order.  But I haven't read it in detail or really tried to fully understand everything it's saying.

Comment: @PeterCordes 

Comment: Thanks for that wiki link about SC.  IDK if I'd seen it before, but if so I hadn't taken in the point it was making about linearizability being SC plus strict ordering in absolute time.  Re: a single location, the top of that article says: *Coherence deals with maintaining a global order in which writes to a single location or single variable are seen by all processors. Consistency deals with the ordering of operations to multiple locations with respect to all processors.*  - I still think coherence is the more appropriate term for a single var, like in https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19

Comment: @PeterCordes For the original question, could you please post a formal response so that I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: This comment thread has touched on so many more topics than what's in the actual question.  The question body seems to be pretty trivially answerable with "yes, that's correct" plus some links to Q&As about wall-clock time being the wrong way to think about lock-free atomics when designing algorithms.  (Which is why I just commented initially.)  But IDK how much scope there is to expand the question without making it too broad.

Comment: If you want to draft a community-wiki answer out of my comments or something, I'd be happy to look over it and edit it into shape given a framework to start with.  (Or post my own answer after seeing what shape of answer you think you want.)  Bedtime for me now, so I don't have the time and energy to write anything significant right now.

Comment: Second thoughts re: consistency vs. coherence: I guess even for ops on a single variable, if you have some pure reads in the same thread as writes, then seq_cst vs. acq/rel or weaker matters for StoreLoad reordering, so I guess consistency can be a relevant concept.  So fair enough, even though that wasn't the case in the example we were discussing with a write-only writer and read-only readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yes, that's correct." from the comments of @Peter Cordes under the question.

Comment: Refer to @Peter Cordes' discussion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).