concurrent fetch_add and compare_exchange_weak interaction
Consider the following interaction between T1 and T2.
Can it happen that T2 will miss the notification from T1 and will suspend?
In other words, can it happen that compare_exchange_weak will succeed and T1 will read a value that is not THREAD_SLEEP after compare_exchange_weak succeeds?
I am confused because in this example, there are no other shared memory variables besides tq_seq_ so why would memory order matter?
To clarify the question. Can it happen that CAS happens at time 0 and succeeds, and T1 performs fetch_add at time 0+Epsilon and chooses the WakeT2 branch?

if we use relaxed
if we use acq_release

#define THREAD_SLEEP 10000000

atomic_long tq_seq_{0};

// T1: Producer Thread
void T1() {
    queue.add(task);   // lets assume that queue is thread-safe.
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);

    // Wake Up Consumer if needed.
    auto current = tq_seq_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (current == THREAD_SLEEP) {
        WakeT2();
    }
}

// T2: Consumer Thread
void T2() {
    while (true) {
        auto start_seq = tq_seq_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        task = queue.pop();
        do_work(task);
        // Attempt to sleep if no notifications arrived
        if (queue.empty() && tq_seq_.compare_exchange_weak(
                start_seq,
                THREAD_SLEEP,
                std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            thread_suspend(); // Suspend T2 until woken by T1
        }
    }
}


If there is no shared memory, you can use std::memory_order_relaxed. As far as I can see from your example, there is no need to have a stricter memory ordering since you have a single atomic variable. Furthermore, if compare_exchange_weak succeeds, T1 will immediately see the correct value of atomic tq_seq_, no matter the ordering. Note that I am talking here only about correctness of what you have shown, not about what is sensible thing to do. You would have to provide more context for the latter.

I thought the same but I suspect we are both wrong. There are similar SO questions where people say that it's not guaranteed that memory stores are flushed when using relaxed stores. in other words, it's not guaranteed that T1 observes the latest STORE from T2 when relaxed-loading tq_seq_ in T1

That makes no sense whatsoever. Memory ordering has nothing to do with atomic variable itself. It is a barrier imposed by atomic variable on the rest of the memory, not on the atomic variable itself. If atomic store had no guarantee, it would be pretty much useless. And even if there was no guarantee, changing memory ordering would not add that guarantee.

This is the answer I was talking about:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292095/mesi-protocol-stdatomic-does-it-ensure-all-writes-are-immediately-visible

This is in relation to other loads on different variables. But the answer says it: "If you mean committing from the store buffer into L1d cache, then yes, that's the moment when a store becomes globally visible". So, when you store it into L1 cache, it propagates to other threads' L1 caches.

Relating to your edit, it will happen regardless of the memory order. Even if the answer was "no, it won't happen", that would still be independent of the memory order.

@lobelk: If T1 had been during a .load instead of an RMW, it could potentially load the old value at the OP's time 0+Epsilon because real CPUs use invalidation queues.  This is why looking at time / clock cycles across threads instead of just order makes things more complicated, and turns it into a CPU-architecture question.  (And of course a relaxed load could have completed (read from cache) early, before the other thread invalidated the cache line, and before some other operations on other variables that were sequenced before it.  But I'd still call that running early, at time 0-delta)

But yes, this case is simple, both operations are RMWs on the same object so they're serialized with each other.  They can only take a value while the having exclusive ownership of the cache line.  It's not possible for the load side to take a value from before the other thread's store but for the store to come after in the modification order, that's what [atomics.order] p10 is about. https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.order#10

(See also Is the order of a side effect in the modification order determined by when the side effect is produced? - with some threads doing pure stores and loads to a variable that RMWs are happening on, things are a lot less simple.  But that's not happening here, just two threads doing RMWs and a load.)

@PeterCordes thank you! Are you saying relaxed_order operations should be enough so that notifications won't be lost?

No, whichever RMW runs second will see the value from the other.  I just wanted to put some caution on general statements like lobelk's T1 will immediately see the correct value of atomic.  Actually, T1's RMWs will miss in cache after that point, but any that complete after regaining ownership of the cache line will see the new value.

It's possible for WakeT2(); to run before T2 actually reaches thread_suspend();, so thread_suspend(); will need the ability to atomically check-and-sleep like Linux futex.
Or an API like C++20 .wait which watches for the value to be different from what you specified, providing the same thing (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait).  But there's no way for .fetch_add to miss a THREAD_SLEEP value.

compare_exchange_weak can fail spuriously so T2's loop continues and tries to pop from an empty queue.  Many lock-free queue implementations have a blocking pop operation that will sleep until a writer adds something, so you normally don't need this.    Anyway, compare_exchange_strong would avoid this problem, only failing if T1 had incremented in the meantime.  None of this reasoning involves time, just order and synchronization.

yes, I use Linux eventfd for that which does not miss notifications. But I did have a bug where T1 skipped the WakeT2 call and T2 suspended, and happens only on ARM64. Changing the memory order from relaxed to ack_rel fixed the issue, but now I am trying to understand if it is a real fix or just something that hides the symptom.

Especially on ARM64, making the fetch_add use release instead of a separate atomic_thread_fence(release) would be more efficient and should be equivalent.  Either way prevents the sequence update from becoming visible before all the effects of queue.add.  Acquire (as part of acq_rel) would stop the load side from coming after next iteration's queue.add, assuming it's called in a loop.  Perhaps that can let the same sequence number be visible across two pops?  But the queue wouldn't be empty.  Hrm.

@PeterCordes Yes, my mistake was that I failed to draw distinct line between real time and modification order and to use misleading terms like "immediately". All I wanted to say is this: once an atomic RMW starts to happen in T2, the next read of the same atomic is guaranteed to see that value, no matter the memory order. So, it is not possible that atomic read in T1 does not see tq_seq_ being THREAD_SLEEP if that atomic read is after atomic RMW in T2. Real time is irrelevant.

I think you should add to the question a more precise explanation of what your suspend and wake functions do, and their exact semantics.  If the wake is called before the other thread enters suspend, do you have a guarantee that the suspend will return immediately?  If wake is called n times, do you have a guarantee that the next n calls to suspend will return immediately?  Most suspend/wake-type functions don't; e.g. with ISO C++ std::atomic wait/notify or with condition variables, if a notify occurs when nobody is waiting, it's simply lost.
